# Is it possible to turn off move staling in smash ultimate?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I was playing smash on someone else's switch and someone there said they thought that move staling had been turned off since the people playing there often didn't know much about smash and often would only know a few moves.  I was curious so I checked the ruleset and couldn't even find an option to turn move staling off.

were they mistaken or is it possible to turn move staling off?

Comment: For those that are unaware: "move staling" is a mechanic that reduces the damage of moves that are being used repeatedly. Not to be confused with "stalling", which is a strategy of wasting time (avoid losing by letting the timer run out) through various means (including running away and exploits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can only switch off move staling in Training Mode**. Useful for testing combos or for damage calculation.

Staling is meant to discourage repeated attacks and encourage using a character's entire moveset. The staling queue resets once you are KOed or use other moves.

Your friends were probably mistaking with Training Mode or thought it was also available in Smash Mode.

Comment: k thanks for the confirmation.  guess i can do combos there without wondering if they won't work do to no staling now =D